# Canvas - Using custom fonts

Tags: canvas, font-face, html5-canvas

Im using a special font for a website using @font-face. The font renders ok with DOM elements but it doesnt for the CANVAS. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the demo: http://enriquemorenotent.com/demos/cube2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, funny thing. All I had to change was:

```
context.font = "36px myFont bold";
```

for

```
context.font = '36px "myFont" bold';
```